# rust serde_json expected value at line 1 column 1

Tags: rust, deserialization, serde

I have this function:

```
pub async fn ai_request<T: DeserializeOwned>(
    context: String,
    position: &str,  // user or system etc
) -> T {
    let llm_response: String =
        ai_task(context,position).await;
            
    eprintln!("llm_response {}",&llm_response);
    let decoded_response: Result<T, _> = serde_json::from_str(llm_response.as_str());
    match decoded_response {
        Ok(response) => return response,
        Err(err) => {
            eprintln!("Failed to decode ai response from serde_json: {}", err);
            unimplemented!("Use this get rid of rustc mismatch type error"); // Temporary placeholder
        }
    };
```

it fails at this line

```
let decoded_response: Result<T, _> = serde_json::from_str(llm_response.as_str());
```

this line `eprintln!("llm_response {}",&llm_response);` prints this on terminal:

```
llm_response build a fullstack website with user login and logout
```

however serialization is failing. it is passing correct type. I could not figure out how to debug it

this is type of `serde_json::from_str`

```
pub fn from_str<'a, T>(s: &'a str) -> Result<T>
where
    T: de::Deserialize<'a>,
```

it expects a string slice and I am passing a string slice. rust compiler is aware that I am passing a correct type `llm_response.as_str()`. If I pass `llm_response`, I get warning:

```
expected &str, found String
```

Comment: The response seems to be just string, not JSON. What kind of data do you expect to receive?

Comment: `build a fullstack website with user login and logout` is not valid JSON, `"build a fullstack website with user login and logout"` would be (note the added quotes).